# ng-repeat th element remove attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So i have the following `ng-repeat`:

```
<th ng-repeat="field in tableFields" translate="{{field.headerTitle | translate}}"
    ts-criteria="{{field.sortable ? field.fieldKey : null}}">
    <label class="i-checks" ng-if="field.isCheckbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkAll" ng-change="selectAll(checkAll)">
        <i></i>
    </label>
</th>
```

This works fine however due to some errors in an external script the `ts-criteria` should not be set if `field.fieldKey is null`. So my question is how can i remove the attribute completely?

Comment: please post your ts-criteria code

Comment: @SantoshShinde ts-criteria is from an external lib. https://github.com/mattiash/angular-tablesort

Comment: use  switch case or conditional statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If think a good option would be to use `ng-switch` to choose if your attribute should be set, or not.

Don't have your full code, but it would be something like:

```
<div ng-switch on="myVar">
    <th ng-switch-when="true" ts-criteria>ts-criteria here</th>
    <th ng-switch-default>not here</th>
</div>
```

[**Here is a demo on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9qw8wdqo/)

*Try it by changing `myVar` value*.